# Как выровнять блочные элементы?

Tags: html, css

Не знаю, как выровнять блочные элементы, чтобы они были ровно напротив друг друга. Для размещения элементов на странице всегда использовал `margin`, но иногда стал замечать, что блочные элементы не ровно напротив друг друга, а немного в другом положении. Например, у меня есть 2 блочных элемента:

```
#blockabout1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 200px;
  background-color: #CEECF5;
}

#blockabout2 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -530px 950px;
  background-color: #CEECF5;
}
```

И как сделать так, чтобы они были РОВНО друг напротив  друга? Какие еще свойства можно использовать для выравнивания элементов, кроме margin?

Comment: `position:absolute; left:...; top:...`

Comment: `display:inline-block; `

Comment: Можете приложить к этому и HTML?